# Microsoft SQL Linked MySQL Server - Can't query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I've setup a linked MySQL server on our Microsoft SQL Server.  I can run this query successfully in MSSQL Management Studio...

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM countries')
```

When I run this from a website in PHP though, I get this error...

```
Message: Failed to query SQL statement. Reason: Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.
```

Any ideas what I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the workaround is to shift the “SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF” statement just below the linked server call. And to be on the safer side apply the “SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON” statement at the end of the sp/query.

**update**

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM countries')
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/1d501b57-fc58-4fbe-9bec-6c38ad158a62

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not creating or using any stored procedure though.  I'm just trying to run a simple select query using OPENQUERY().

Comment: I tried your updated answer and unfortunately it did not work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok I got it to work with the following PHP code.  I'm using the [Kohana LEAP ORM](http://orm.spadefootcode.com/) here, but the main point to getting this to work is to run these as separate queries in the same connection.

    `$sql = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM states') part";
    $connection = DB_Connection_Pool::instance()->get_connection(new DB_DataSource('production_tm'));
    $connection->execute('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
    $connection->execute('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
    $res = $connection->query($sql);`